# Certain mouse button combination changes mouse sensitivity

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

For years I've been dealing with a weird bug that would arise randomly and change the sensitivity of my mouse pointer in Windows 10. I could never pin down what was making it change, making it impossible to search for, and there were many false equivalences between similar-but-slightly-different use cases reported by other people.

After spending some time on it earlier this week, I figured out that my mouse sensitivity appears to be bound to the MIDDLE+RIGHT CLICK shortcut. Holding down the middle button and then clicking the right mouse button changes the sensitivity between several positions. This is most often caused by accident when drumming on the mouse buttons.
(I hope Google links people to this page to help uncover some of the randomness.)

My question is: *what is causing this?* Is this a default Windows 10 shortcut that is poorly documented? Is it a consequence of MouseKeys, which I use? I use a CST Trackball with Microsoft's generic drivers, so it isn't mouse software intervening. I also have a Wacom PTZ-630 tablet but scouring the settings doesn't seem to suggest this as a feature offered by the software.

Answer (score 0):

This is an in-built "feature" of CST Trackballs.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Trackballs/comments/8cdslu/cst_cording_middle_click_right_click_can_this_be/